# Rebuild DIV id's

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of php that outputs divs (depending on how many is in the array) and assigns that div with an id (i.e div_1, div_2) etc

I also set a hidden field with the count of how many divs were outputted (divcount)

So lets say I have 5 divs then the id's of the div's will be

- div_1,
- div_2,
- div_3
- etc etc
- and the hidden field (divcount) will be set to 5

If div_2 gets deleted, I set the divcount hidden field to 4.

What I need to do now is rebuild the other div's id's to be:

- div_1,
- div_2,
- div_3,
- div_4,
  but currently I am left with div_1, div_3, div_4, div_5

I guess I need a loop to loop through each div and assign the id of THAT div the value of the loop

i.e

- div_1 id becomes div_1
- div_3 id becomes div_2
- div_4 id becomes div_3
- div_5 id becomes div_4

Can anyone advise on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each` method.

```
$('div[id^="div_"]').each(function(i){
   this.id = 'div_'+(++i)
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJhJP/1/)

Answer (score 1):

jquery's each function is the way to go...

```
var tally = 1;
$("div[id*=div_]").each( function() {
    $(this).prop("id","div_"+tally);
    tally++;
});
```