# Loop all siblings div and update its id

Tags: jquery, html

I have list of DIV as following.

```
<div id="div_0">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_1">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_2">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_3">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_4">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_5">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_6">Some Content</div>
```

I have written code to remove any of this div on the fly. So my problem is I want to update ID of next all div by -1 in ID. So If I click cross icon which removes `<div id="div_2">` I want to update my other div's as following.

```
<div id="div_0">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_1">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_2">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_3">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_4">Some Content</div>
<div id="div_5">Some Content</div>
```

Removing code working fine. I just want to update ID's of other div. You can see, there are only 5 DIV now with updated ID. I am not very good at jQuery.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your code effort?

Comment: Here is the [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215268/rebuild-div-ids?rq=1) to your Question. You just have to modify it little according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. and I have tried with jQuery.each but I think now I got the point. My selector was wrong to get ID. Thanks for similar question link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do here is, count the div that is present after removing.

It would be easy if you add a class to it or add a div (with id) enclosing it.

```
<div id="divID">
   <div id="div_0">Some Content</div>
   <div id="div_1">Some Content</div>
   <div id="div_2">Some Content</div>
   <div id="div_3">Some Content</div>
   <div id="div_4">Some Content</div>
   <div id="div_5">Some Content</div>
   <div id="div_6">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

and  count it after you remove certain element

```
 ...remove(); //your code
 $('#divID').siblings().each(function(n) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'div_' + n);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing use something like this:

```
// you can specify selector here 
$('div').each(function(n) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'div_' + n);
});
```